# swift: How to ask for HealtKit permission?

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, authorization

I'd like my iOS application to interact with Apple's HealKit.

To request authorization I'm using this few lines:

```
public func requestHealthkit() {
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    var shareTypes = Set<HKSampleType>()
    shareTypes.insert(HKSampleType.workoutType())
    var readTypes = Set<HKObjectType>()
    readTypes.insert(HKObjectType.workoutType())

    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: shareTypes, read: readTypes) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            print("[HealthKit] request Authorization succeed!")
        } else {
            print("[HealthKit] request Authorization failed!")
        }
        if let error = error { print("[HealthKit] An error occurred: \(error)") }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1 (Using this way will not work either)** :

```
healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: shareTypes, read: readTypes) { (success, error) in
   print("I'm not called. However! :p")
}
```

**Edit 2 (This is my info.plist)** : 
I have added **NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription** to the `info.plist`-file and turned on health kit capability.

[image: image 1]

And these are my capabilities settings:

### [image: image 2]

But calling the function `requestHealthkit()` **will wether work nor produce any error message or log**, there just -> N-O-T-H-I-N-G.

Is this the right way to request HealthKit authorization or am I doing something completely wrong? (*2. scenario is the very likely case*)

Help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have added `NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription` to your info.plist and turned on your health kit capability.

Comment: I have added all needed Tags to info.plist & of course activated HealthKit @GIJOW.

Comment: There is no of course while troubleshooting an issue @Jonas0000. I think you meant HealthKit

Comment: Yeah, you are right. HealthKit - Not AudioKit - sneeze* DEVELOPERS sneeze

Comment: Your `healthStore` needs or be a property or it will be deallocated as soon as the function returns and before the user is promoted for access

Comment: I can not really get your thought @Paulw11. If you thought of declaring just a instance variable like `var healthStore : HKHealthStore?`-this will not solve the problem. Maybe you like to share some example code - would be very appreciated. :-)

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. Why wouldn’t it solve the problem? Have you tried

Comment: Yeah - that's the solution that instantly comes to my mind looking at the problem. Yeah - I was already testing it but it doesn't seems to change anything. I'm absolutely clueless W-H-Y?? @Paulw11

Comment: I tested your code and even without using a property it worked.  Have you already run your app and responded to the health access prompt?  Once that has happened the user won't be prompted in the app again; they need to change Healthkit access in the Health app.  You can delete the app from the device/simulator to re-trigger the prompt,

Comment: Huh? Thats completely crazy. Yeah I've tested my application on my physic iPhone. I've reinstalled the app nearly a million times but I can not get it working... The status of the permission says in every case `notDetermined`. So would you be so kind to share your **full** code you're using for-Im that clueless?

Comment: Are you still there? @Paulw11

Comment: Please stop using the Objective-C tag for Swift questions. Your title states Swift. The code in your question is Swift. Nothing about your question is about the Objective-C programming language.

Comment: @Jonas0000 Here is my code - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/11cc3da5b9502a785073a5cd3c98ef2d I just created a new single view application and added your code into the view controller

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Paulw11. It seems like you're right. The code is working quiet well. But please have a look at this update to my question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528588/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-swift) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully presented the request form. Have a look to this other question ([HealthKit - requestAuthorization(toShare:read:completion:) always succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233297/healthkit-requestauthorizationtosharereadcompletion-always-succeeds)). Looks like the types used into your set are not the expected.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
        if let hk = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate?)?.healthStore {
            self.requestHealthkit(hk)
        }
    }
}

private func requestHealthkit(_ healthStore:HKHealthStore) {
    let writableTypes: Set<HKSampleType> = [
        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning)!,
        HKWorkoutType.workoutType(),
        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!,
        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned)!,
        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!
    ]
    let readableTypes: Set<HKSampleType> = [
        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning)!,
        HKWorkoutType.workoutType(),
        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!,
        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned)!,
        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!
    ]


    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: writableTypes, read: readableTypes) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            print("[HealthKit] request Authorization succeed!")
        } else {
            print("[HealthKit] request Authorization failed!")
        }
        if let error = error { print("[HealthKit] An error occurred: \(error)") }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer - It seems like my code is also working but just with this issue (same thing for your code). Please look at this update to my question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528588/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-swift) :-)